# Deleting Blocks of code that meet a condition

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have very large text file that is basically a log of messages with a `{` as a separator in between the messages. I want to delete the blocks between the `{` if they meet a certain condition. In the example below I want to delete the middle message block that has `EVENT_TYPE = BDE` and leave the two `ABC` messages.  File is on a Linux box so I have access all your normal `grep`, `sed`, `awk` etc. I can use these processes to find the `EVENT_TYPE` but not sure how to then find the larger block and delete it.

```
}
/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 2342
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 1299
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
} 

/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 889
EVENT_TYPE = BDE
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 778 
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
} 

/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 123
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 345
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}
```

Comment: Is the initial `}` at the top of the sample meant to be there? If all of these blocks are separated by at least one blank line (before and after) it becomes much easier.

Comment: this could be enough: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="}"} !/EVENT_TYPE = BDE/ && NF' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gawk for multi-character RS you can set RS to treat each block as a single record and then just test within than record as usual. We use `NR > 1` to disregard the unwanted first (empty) record that arises from the data beginning with the record separator (assuming it does, it's not clear from your partial sample).

```
$ gawk -v RS='/type/' 'NR > 1 && !/EVENT_TYPE = BDE/ { printf "/type/%s", $0 }' file
/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 2342
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 1299
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}

/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 123
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 345
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever input data has name=value pairs I find it most convenient/robust/maintainable/extensible to first create an array (`f[]` below) of that mapping for each record (`rec` below) and then access the values by their names for testing, printing, etc.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *= *" }
NF { rec = rec $0 ORS; f[$1] = $2 }
/^}/ {
    if ( f["EVENT_TYPE"] != "BDE" ) {
        print rec
    }
    rec = ""
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 2342
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 1299
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}

/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 123
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 345
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/{/{
  val=""
}
/}/{
  if(found=="" && val){
     print val ORS $0
  }
  found=val=""
  next
}
/EVENT_TYPE = BDE/{
  found=1
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(val && found==""){
    print val ORS $0
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$ vim -es '+g/EVENT_TYPE = BDE/exe "norm! dap"' '+%print' '+q!' file
```

Output:

```
}
/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 2342
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 1299
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}

/type/ - DataEvents = {
VALUE = 123
EVENT_TYPE = ABC
VALUE_YESTERDAY = 345
HAS_DELAY = false
SEND_TIME_RT = 18:55:21.224+00:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' by gnu sed

```
sed -Ez 's/\{[^{}]*EVENT_TYPE\s*=\s*BDE[^}]*\}//' d
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/EVENT_TYPE = BDE/d}' file
```

Gather up lines between `{` and `}` and if those lines contain `EVENT_TYPE = BDE` then delete them.